# iPhone Picker Help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, interface-builder

I have a picker setup, and it is displaying the output of the picker to a label.  However, I have to click a button for that too happen.  How can I display the picker contents a user is selecting without having to hit a button.

Edit:  I forgot to mention that my picker has two columns.  If anyone has code examples that would be great.

Comment: Does anyone have a little code example, i'm a little lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the didSelectRow method. Once a row is selected that method will run.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html

This does not work so well with multiple components as once one component is selected it grabs the values for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a UIPickerViewDelegate, and then you can use the appropriate callback method to modify your label (probably pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:). See this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDelegate).

Answer (score 0):

To perform an action when the user selects a row in UIPickerView, you need to set the pikcerview's delegate and implement `– pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`.